# Хранение паролей в приложении Android

Tags: android, криптография, java

Доброго времени суток. Дописав (наконец-то) свой клиент для сайта, задумался, как хранить пароли пользователей... Насколько надежно хранить cookie и пароли в

```
getSharedPreferences("LoginPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Как вообще можно защититься от воровства паролей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя хранить пароли. То есть нельзя ни в коде, ни в преференсах, ни в БД, вообще нигде.

С одним небольшим уточнением: можно если зашифровать пароль. Но сразу же возникнет вопрос а где хранить пароль от шифра, которым зашифрован пароль и круг замыкается :)

Но не все так печально. Есть 2 подхода:

1. Самый правильный способ: хранить хэш пароля и отдельно (если требуется) соль к паролю.
2. Зашифровать сам пароль, а в качестве пароля к шифру, которым зашифрован пароль использовать идентификатор устройства, MAC адрес, идентификатор сим карты и проч. В общем привязать зашифрованное содержимое пароля к устройству, так чтобы при утечке данных невозможно было дешифровать пароль.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, но ведь хранят же!!!

Та же мозилла (Tools->Options->SavedPasswords...)

Comment: @avp Да, Mozilla хранит и причем сволочь даже не шифрует ведь - просто кодирует в base64 и все :) Ну если только юзер сам не установил мастер пароль, которым будут шифроваться пароли. Мастер пароль как и положено Mozilla нигде не хранит. Так что все правильно. Не уподобляйтесь Mozilla!

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вы хотите организовать автоматическую авторизацию, чтобы пользователь лишний раз не вводил пароль!? Может для этого лучше использовать механизм типа "remember me" и хранить у себя не данные юзера, а хэш который выдаст сервер? Если конечно есть такая возможность

Comment: такой возможности, к сожалению, нет

Answer (score 0):

Хранение связки логин/пароль в SharedPreferences не даст вам максимум безопасности, однако это надёжнее сохранения в файл.

Но строки с данными можно зашифровать, использовав [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220925) метод. И по совету @Lookingfor можно получать Secret key для шифрации с сервера, ведь если вы положите его в APK, то его можно будет декомпилировать и посмотреть. Хотя я уверен, что это никто делать не будет.

Answer (score -2):

я думаю достаточно хранить в преференсах